# ringtone is not available on vline

Tags: vline

I am making application on vLine

I made it to video chat each other with sounds.

but,it doesn't ring ringtone.

Is there anything special I have to do for ringing ringtone?

this [explanation](https://vline.com/developer/docs/vline.js/vline.MediaSession) looks there is not some special setting for ringtone.

```
var client, vlinesession;var lastMsg;
var vlineClient = (function(){    
    if('{{vlineData.serviceId}}' == 'YOUR_SERVICE_ID' || '{{vlineData.serviceId}}' == 'YOUR_SERVICE_ID'){
        alert('Please make sure you have created a vLine service and that you have properly set the $serviceID and $apiSecret variables in classes/Vline.php file.');     

    }
    var authToken = '{{ vlineData.authToken }}',
        serviceId = '{{ vlineData.serviceId }}',
        profile = {"displayName": '{{ vlineData.displayName }}', "id": '{{ vlineData.id }}'};




    // Create vLine client  
    window.vlineClient = client_ = vline.Client.create({"serviceId": serviceId, "ui": true,
        'uiVideoPanel':'showvideo'
    });
    // Add login event handler

    client_.on('login', onLogin);
    client_.login(serviceId, profile, authToken).done(this.init_,this);
    // Do login
//
    //
    // 
    //  


  function initCallButton(button) {
    var userId = button.attr('data-userid');

    // fetch person object associated with username
    vlinesession.getPerson(userId).done(function(person) {
      // update button state with presence
      function onPresenceChange() {
        if(person.getPresenceState() == 'online'){
            button.removeClass().addClass('active');
        }else{
            button.removeClass().addClass('disabled');
        }
        button.attr('data-presence', person.getPresenceState());
      }

      // set current presence
      onPresenceChange();

      // handle presence changes
      person.on('change:presenceState', onPresenceChange);


      // start a call when button is clicked
      button.click(function() {
              if (person.getId() == vlinesession.getLocalPersonId()) {
            alert('You cannot call yourself. Login as another user in an incognito window');
            return;
              }
          if(button.hasClass('active'))
                        //    person.postMessage("Hello there");
                        //    console.log("send message");
            person.startMedia();

      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client has a setRingtone function that lets you set a single file
path or an array of paths, say of mp3 and ogg file formats. It got
dropped off from the docs. You can set the your ringtone after you
create the client. We will make sure the docs get exported in the next builds.

```
    /**
     * Set the sound to be played as the ringtone for calls. The parameter takes an
     * array of paths, so that you can pass in different file formats like
     * ogg and mp3 for cross browser support.
     * @param {!string|!Array.<!string>} audioFilePath path to audio file(s).
     */
     setRingtone(<audioPath(s)>)
```